# kubernetes Ingress integration with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

am trying to integrate my Application which is deployed(AWS) using K8 with AWS API Gateway.

AWS APIG doesn't support SNI with VPC Link. The AWS support team requested to disable the SNI on my ingress.

Question : 
1.) How can I disable an SNI.
2.) My Deployment has two applications running and is using ingress to route the traffic to my domains namely  dev.test.com and prod.test.com. If I disable the SNI by any means does it going to affect my services?

Comment: Can you post your ingress resource?